# What does it mean $v\in\partial f(w)$?

Tags: functions

Given a function $f$ and a vector $w$, what does it mean $v\in\partial f(w)$? As much as I know the $\partial A$ sign is the edge of the set $A$. But here $f(w)$ is a number.

Comment: This strikes me as an unusual usage. Can you provide a quote of at least the full sentence (ideally the paragraph) in which it was used?

Comment: "Claim: If $f$ is $\lambda$-strongly convex then for every $w,u$ and $v\in\partial f(w)$ we have
$$\langle w-u,v\rangle\geq f(w)-f(u)+{\lambda\over 2}||w-u||^2$$
". It is taken from this book:
https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~shais/UnderstandingMachineLearning/understanding-machine-learning-theory-algorithms.pdf
page 195.

Comment: @KaboMurphy, why not make that an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This notation is from convex analysis. $\partial f(w)$ is the sub-differential of $f$ at $w$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subderivative